# How to list all the products of a paticular attributes in CMS page magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-attribute, product-list, cms-pages

I need to display All the products by a specific product attribute in CMS page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new widget in cms page.

1) Open your CMS Page by **admin->CONTENT->Pages**

2) Then open content tab and click on the second icon which is widget icon to add a new widget.

[image]

3) Now Select

**Widget Type**: Catalog Product List

**Condition**: Select your attribute name and value

[image]

For Example I set condition like price(attribute) greater than 50(Value)

[image]

4) Now click on insert widget to add widget.

Save CMS page.  Done...!

Comment: in this case it will load based on that attribute value..
what i need is:
eg: attribute = color
 i need to list the product  with all the values of attribute

Comment: @SUBINCHANDRAN for that you need to create custom collection with attribute filter. By widget you must need to select attribute value.